# Changing font of PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

How can I change the font of a existing PDF file with iTextSharp in C#?

I want to change the whole documents font into one e.g. Arial

Comment: What exactly are your expectations? Does it suffice to change the fonts of all text elements? You are aware that the result may look very ugly if the font used before has different metrics than the new one, letters might overlap or be extremely far from each other, text lines might go beyond the right document border, etc... And even this ugly solution isn't always possible as character mapping information may not be included in the font information in the document which in case of custom encodings may make it impossible to know which character is which.

Answer (score 7):

Finally I solved the problem.
The following code will open an existing Pdf file and will change all its font to 'Braille' as per my expectation.

```
 private static void ChangeFont()
        {


            string strFile = @"E:\\xyz.pdf";
            string OutputFile = @"E:\\xyz1.pdf";
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(strFile);

            //Get first page,Generally we get font information on first page,however we can loop throw pages e.g for(int i=0;i<=pdfReader.NumberOfPages;i++)
                PdfDictionary cpage = pdfReader.GetPageN(1);
                if (cpage == null)
                    return;
                PdfDictionary dictFonts = cpage.GetAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES).GetAsDict(PdfName.FONT);
                if (dictFonts != null)
                {
                    foreach (var font in dictFonts)
                    {
                        var dictFontInfo = dictFonts.GetAsDict(font.Key);

                        if (dictFontInfo != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var f in dictFontInfo)
                            {
                                //Get the font name-optional code
                                var baseFont = dictFontInfo.Get(PdfName.BASEFONT);
                                string strFontName = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(baseFont.GetBytes(), 0,
                                                                                          baseFont.Length);
                                //


                                //Remove the current font
                                dictFontInfo.Remove(PdfName.BASEFONT);
                                //Set new font eg. Braille, Areal etc
                                dictFontInfo.Put(PdfName.BASEFONT, new PdfString("Braille"));
                                break;

                            }
                        }


                    }

            }

            //Now create a new document with updated font
            using (FileStream FS = new FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                using (Document Doc = new Document())
                {
                    using (PdfCopy writer = new PdfCopy(Doc, FS))
                    {
                        Doc.Open();
                        for (int j = 1; j <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; j++)
                        {
                            writer.AddPage(writer.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, j));
                        }
                        Doc.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            pdfReader.Close();

        }
```

Comment: thanks. How can i change font color of pdf by using above code

Comment: You should remove the `foreach (var f in dictFontInfo)`

Comment: This code is a mess, iteration, and declaration which are not used. Also the code not working. It will not change the base font name in PDF.