# change existing font in pdf file itextsharp c#

Tags: c#, itext

I want to change existing font style regular to bold, <s>increase font size. Like if font style is regular I want to change it to bold. If font size 10 then i want to increase or decrease one size it(10->11 or 10->9)</s>

After searching on this topic I found this code but this gives only the information of font and it doesn't change style <s>and size</s>

```
        string OutputFile = "font.pdf";
        //PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(strFile);
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(mStream.ToArray());

        //Get first page,Generally we get font information on first page,however we can loop throw pages e.g for(int i=0;i<=pdfReader.NumberOfPages;i++)
        PdfDictionary cpage = pdfReader.GetPageN(1);
        if (cpage == null)
            return;
        PdfDictionary dictFonts = cpage.GetAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES).GetAsDict(PdfName.FONT);
        if (dictFonts != null)
        {
            foreach (var font in dictFonts)
            {
                var dictFontInfo = dictFonts.GetAsDict(font.Key);

                if (dictFontInfo != null)
                {
                    //Get the font name-optional code
                    var baseFont = dictFontInfo.Get(PdfName.BASEFONT);
                    string strFontName = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(baseFont.GetBytes(), 0, baseFont.Length);

                    //var bf = BaseFont.CreateFont((PRIndirectReference)baseFont);
                    //iTextSharp.text.Font exFont =new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf,20f);


                    //Remove the current font
                    //dictFontInfo.Remove(PdfName.BASEFONT);
                    //Set new font eg. Braille, Areal etc
                    //dictFontInfo.Put(PdfName.BASEFONT, new PdfString("Braille"));
                }
            }
        }

        //Now create a new document with updated font
        using (FileStream FS = new FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            using (Document Doc = new Document())
            {
                using (PdfCopy writer = new PdfCopy(Doc, FS))
                {
                    Doc.Open();
                    for (int j = 1; j <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; j++)
                    {
                        writer.AddPage(writer.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, j));
                    }
                    Doc.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        pdfReader.Close();
```

i want also to change some font like Arial to some other font.

Comment: You are assuming that PDF is a format that is well suited for editing. That assumption is wrong. Please tell whoever asked you to meet this requirement that you respectfully decline the assignment on account of the fact that it's a mission impossible. It's also funny that you think that the font size is stored in the font dictionary. That's completely wrong too.

Comment: please explain your question properly

Comment: [use this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15241639/6207514) to change font but not got success

Comment: @BrunoLowagie  thank u sir to clear my question. it is possible to change existing font. when i debug this code bold font name come with -Bold so that font is bold. is there sample to change font regular to font bold

Comment: In only a very few cases you can change fonts in a PDF by simply replacing its base name (in particular the font must not be embedded), and even then the result PDFs only look acceptable if the replacement font has the same metrics (in particular glyph widths) as the original font.

Comment: @mkl any sample to achieve that

Comment: In PDF, text is added at absolute positions. The process of adding text to a PDF depends largely on the metrics of the font: *how much space does every glyph need?* Different fonts have different metrics. The *A* in Arial has a different dimension than the **A** in Times Roman. If you replace one font with another in a PDF, this difference in metrics will cause a really ugly layout, because changing the font, doesn't change the positions of the text in the PDF. I repeat: you should respectfully decline the assignment.

Comment: @mayurjansari *"any sample to achieve that"* - the one you linked a few comments before... As you said that it didn't work for you, though, your situation likely is not one of those *very few cases you can change fonts in a PDF by simply replacing its base name*. Simply said, PDF is not meant for such manipulations, and depending on the circumstances achieving even a small such manipulation can require code specific for your very document.

Comment: @mkl ok got it. i have one question more. regular font to bold font in existing pdf. retesting that sample code to add suffix -Bold for in font name to get bold font if that not work please help me on that code.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie ok sir i m skip change font in existing font change in pdf portion.

Comment: *"i have one question more..."* - The issues here are similar as mentioned above. If the base font name change help at all, metrics will still differ so you get ugly artifacts. And it won't work for embedded fonts.

Comment: Go back to the original process where the pdf was created, and change the font there *before* the pdf is created. For example if you did "Save to PDF" in Word, go to the original Word file, change the font there, and then "Save to PDF" again. If you don't have the original Word file any more: tough luck - other commenters have already explained why you have reached a dead end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the font of an existing PDF can not be done in a meaningful, generic way, without risk of messing up the layout.

To illustrate, assume you have the following text.
I'm using | to indicate a page-boundary.

```
Lorem Ipsum Dolor   |  
Sit Amet Consectetur|    
Nunc                |
```

If I make this text larger, or make it bold, or even italic, it is likely to take up more space. That means the word 'Consectetur' will no longer fit on the line.

PDF (unlike a Word document) does not automatically re-flow its content. The content would simply appear to go over the page boundary (and depending on the viewer you are using it might vanish).

The real problem is that the PDF format does not have the same information as the word format.

- where are word-boundaries located?
- where are paragraph boundaries?
- (what language is this text being written in?)

All of these are important when performing layout for a document. And none of these are naturally present in a PDF document.

Comment: ok i understand. i m doing mission impossible as per BrunoLowagie sir now i understand hole procedure. I dont know whether it is possible or not. so I asked this question. thank u so much to guide me on this topic.

Comment: To make this clear to other users, it makes sense to accept this answer.

Comment: I agree: accepting an answer shows other readers that the question is closed.